# Disable login form alert for IsAuthenticated API views - DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have some views that have the `IsAuthenticated` permission class. However, whenever I access these views, a JS alert pops up asking for credentials like so:

[image: DRF login]

How can I disable this, so that users are unable to log in via this view? I want users to **only** be able to log in via the `Login` view, which has a 2FA system.

Comment: What's the authentication class for that view set to? If it's not set, what is [DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#default_authentication_classes) set to?

Comment: Set to `"DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ],` @NickODell

Comment: Note that BasicAuthentication will allow a user to log in with just a username and password. https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0e3bc2b1e0189ecc143868ca31dd3393a8aa76f4/rest_framework/authentication.py#L61 You'll want to disable that if you want to enforce 2FA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing:

```py
"DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
     "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
]
```

Thank you @nick Odell

Comment: I am facing this issue. Can you help?

Comment: REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}
I have 2 services, 1 is auth service, 1 is communication. this is communication service settings. frontend calls communication API, I get the token in middleware, send it to auth service to validate, and based on that I show a response. but I am constantly getting that popup if token failed or any auth service issue.